# Can I add Selenium jar library and link it with the code in Github?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, selenium, github

I am newbie to **GitHub** and I made an open source project.

I have linked my GitHub project with eclipse.

The code is commited, but it is dependent on Selenium jar file (which is not commited/available on GitHub).

In Eclipse **I have added Selenium jar in Java Build Path** so my code doesn't give compilation errors.

Since I am newbie to GitHub I don't know how to add jar in build path of GitHub(If there is need to do that).

My questions are:

1. Is jar/libraries need to be added on build path of GitHub for project ? If yes then how to do it ?
2. How can we check code compilation errors on GitHub ?

Answer (score 0):

### For Question : 1

In Github first you have to check the gitignore file of your project

For further reference please go through the following links :

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore

Please remove .*jar references from the git ignore file

Keep your third party libraries in your Eclipse Project root directory.

In Eclipse build path Click on **Add Jars** and select the jars from your project root.

This adds a relative classpath for the jars. So even if you switch to  a new machine also you don't need worry about classpath issues just git pull and run the tests.

### For Question 2

Github can't check Java compilation errors.

Github is a Version Control Management and Collaboration tool.